# Strings that include <p></p> tags rendering as HTML content instead of string in DOM query

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I have a series of strings and some of them are formatted like `<p>Text here</p>` and others are formatted like "Text here". The dilemma I have been having is that I want the string to render and actually include the p tags in the string `<p>Text here</p>`. However, this results in the text being wrapped in html paragraph tags.

Essentially, I assign the strings by using 
              `document.getElementById("stringLocation").innerHtml = " <p>Text here</p>"`

How can I successfully use these DOM elements to assign to the dom and include the `<p>` tags as part of the string and not part of the html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign to the `.textContent` property instead of the `.innerHTML` property, and string will be parsed as *text* rather than HTML (ensuring nothing but a text node gets created):

```js
document.getElementById("stringLocation").textContent = " <p>Text here</p>"
```

```html
<pre id="stringLocation"></pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

[HTML Character Codes](https://hightechtele.com/tools/codes) are used for this:

`&#60;p&#62;test&#60;&#47;p&#62;`

```html
&#60;p&#62;test&#60;&#47;p&#62;
```